# How to make state of each react component as independent?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, api

I am creating a card that shows questions and it makes a GET request to my server and shows the answer to the asked question

***The CODE Below of the component shows how the API request is made***

```
  const ChatBoxIItem = ({ message }) => {
  const [ans, setAns] = useState(null);

  getAns(message);
  async function getAns(message) {
    if (!message) {
      return;
    }

    st_chat_asked_question = message;

    let param = {
      question: message,
    };
    param = JSON.stringify(param);
    let url;
    let res_data;
    try {
      console.log(param);
      let curr_data = new Date();

      url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/student/question_answer`;
      res_data = await send_xhr.post(param, url, "application/json");
      res_data = JSON.parse(res_data);

      curr_data = new Date();
      let time = curr_data.toLocaleTimeString();

      if (
        res_data.answers &&
        res_data.answers[0] &&
        res_data.answers[0].score > 0
      ) {
        st_chat_response_data = res_data;
        console.log(res_data);
        setAns(res_data.answers[0].answer);
      } else {
      }
    } catch (e) {

      display_mess("something went wrong", "error", 5000);
      window.scrollTo(0, 100);
      console.log(e);
      return;

    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='st-cs-chat-item'>
      <div className='st-cs-chat-item-header'>
        <p className='st-cs-chat-item-question'>{message}</p>
        <p>{ans ? ans : <p>Searching For Answer</p>}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It's working fine but only for the first component when 2 or more request is made it changes the value of the 1st state also to "Searching for ans"

**When 1st request is made**

[image]

After 1st Request

[image]

**When 2nd request is made (States of both components changes)**
How to fix this issue I don't want to change the states of previous components Need each of them as independent

[image]

Comment: because message is shared between the two component

Comment: try to add the props to the state